# Is it better to have golang statements go out to github or have relative path and why?

Tags: go, import

In golang import statements, is it better to have something like:

```
import(
    'project/package'
)
```

or

```
import(
    'github.com/owner/project/package'
)
```

for files local to your project?

For either option, why would you want to do one over the other?

I ask this because while it's easy and more intuitive to do the first one, I've also seen a lot of big projects like Kubernetes and Etcd do it the second way.

Comment: Second. Only. First does not work. Or did you mean a relative import like "./package"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are *exactly* the same as far as the go build tools are concerned. The fact that `package` is in the directory

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/owner/project/package
```

or in the directory

```
$GOPATH/src/project/package
```

makes no difference.

The only difference is that with the former you can use `go get` to fetch the source automatically, and the latter you have to clone the code yourself.

What you don't want to use are paths relative to the project itself, like

```
import "./project/package"
```

That is not compatible with all the go tools, and is highly discouraged.

Comment: Also, important to note is the second ($GOPATH/src/project/package) will conflict with any other Go package in the world that also chooses to call their package `project/package`. Whereas if you use `github.com/owner/…` or `mydomain.org/…` there can be no conflict, you have a guaranteed globally unique package name (assuming you own the GitHub/Bitbucket account or domain).